# Swift code to make second textfield clear when typing in the second one

Tags: ios, swift

I am teaching myself swift for about a week and a half. I am trying to make a converter that goes from inch to centimeters. I have two textfields, one to punch in inches and one for centimeters. When you type one of them in you hit calculate and it gives you either the conversion for inches or centimeters. The problem I am running into is if you fill one in and then you decide you would rather see the other unit of measure, the numbers are still inputed and the button doesn't really work. How can I have the textfield clear if the user decides to use the other field instead?

Also didn't know if it was possible with the code I am uploading, but I would prefer to get rid of the conversion button all together, so when the user types on unit or the other it immediately fills out the label below. is this possible?

here is the code so far.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var InchesField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CentimetersField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ConversionLabel: UILabel!

    //Only let 1 decimal point
    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.numberStyle = .decimal
        nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        return nf
    }()

   @IBAction func ConversionButton1(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if InchesField.text == "" || CentimetersField.text == "" {
        //either inchfield or centimetersfield text is empty
        ConversionLabel.text = String("Please enter a number")
    }

    if let text = InchesField.text, !text.isEmpty
        {
            //do something if it's not empty
            let inch = Double(InchesField.text!)
            let inCmConvertor = inch! * 2.54

            ConversionLabel.text = String("\(inCmConvertor) Centimters")
    } else
    if let text = CentimetersField.text, !text.isEmpty
    {
            let centimeter = Double(CentimetersField.text!)
            let cmInConvertor = centimeter! / 2.54

        ConversionLabel.text = String("\(cmInConvertor) Inches")
    }

    }
}
```

[Heres a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWyj4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create an IBAction for each Text Field with the **Editing Changed** event in the IBAction creation window.

I tested the code below and it worked:

```
@IBOutlet weak var InchesField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var CentimetersField: UITextField!

@IBAction func InchesFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {
 CentimetersField.text = ""
}

@IBAction func CentimetersFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    InchesField.text = ""
}
```

Don't copy and paste the code, just create the IBActions manually, it will be much simpler.

Good luck with your journey into Swift programming and iOS development.

Comment: Okay thanks so much for quick reply! I drug from story board to the controller and made action func just like above, but when I finish I get error 
    cannot assign value of type 'string' to type 'UITextField!'

Comment: Now what if I wanted to take away characters. If someone accidentally hits a character it crashes the program. I know it has something to do with NSRange or something along those lines